# ASP.NET - Show and hide multiple divs

Tags: html, asp.net

I was wondering if the method I am currently using is a best practice or if I'm possibly using more resources than necessary. With my current site I show and hide divs depending on what the user needs to do or has access to.

Currently I declare my divs like this:

```
<div id="NormalView" runat="server" visible="false">
```

I show and hide my divs with this function:

```
Private Sub DivSelection(ByVal Selection As String)
    NormalView.Visible = False
    FieldRepView.Visible = False
    TestDiv.Visible = False
    Ordering.Visible = False

    If Selection.Equals("NormalView") Then
        GVlowstock.DataBind()
        NormalView.Visible = True
    ElseIf Selection.Equals("FieldRepView") Then
        FieldRepView.Visible = True
    ElseIf Selection.Equals("PasswordChange") Then
        TestDiv.Visible = True
    ElseIf Selection.Equals("Ordering") Then
        Ordering.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm going to be adding more divs to my webpage so I'm afraid that my current method is going to balloon out of control and be more of a hassle than it is useful.

I'm wondering if there is a way to condense this down to fewer lines and be more efficient at the same time. Possibly something like

```
Private Sub DivSelection(divID)
    alldivs.visible = False

    divID.visible = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you considered using an `<asp:LoginView>` which is specifically created for showing different content based on the role of the logged in user?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a loop calling all the div names would do, but I just thought of that. But you can shorten your if statement by referencing the div you want to be visible. just like so:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ShowDiv(div2);
        }

        protected void ShowDiv(System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl divid)
        {
            div1.Visible = false;
            div2.Visible = false;

            divid.Visible = true;
        }
```